# What is the benefit of Laravel's query builder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, builder

I am learning to use Laravel 5, but I am at the query builder phase, and after looking at the first code snippets I think it is really useless when somebody has basic SQL knowledge.

Example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
->where('status', '<>', 1)
->groupBy('status')
->get();
```

What is the purpose of learning query builder syntax if the programmer actually has at least basic knowledge about the SQL language? Moreover, moving advanced queries from a clean SQL language to query builder functions looks like a nightmare...

Comment: Purpose #1 - Prepares the statement and handles bindings for you

Comment: Do note that `DB::raw` will not escape anything, as the name implies.

Comment: Main purpose is making your query more independent from underlaying database system. Like it will work with MySql, but also with some other engine, without need to change your code. Downside of this is that you'll have to spend some time learning something new, but also your queries may be slower. I'm personally also against this, but it's popular this days...

Comment: I also can't imagine upgrading the whole framework because I want to use new database features (upon new db version release) with query builder, On example if MySQL would provide something like a CTE (T-SQL) it would require to upgrade Laravel version

Comment: Another reason to use query builder is if you need to build a query depending on some conditionals. Its easier to build it using method calls than have to deal with sting concatenations.

Comment: start to work with relationships and eloquent and you will get the benefits :)

Comment: Incidentally, if you use `DB::raw(...)` with MySQL specific statements, you lose the benefit of abstraction from the underlying database system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than it provides an interface for when you want to switch database engines (but to be honest, how many times have you seen a large application actually switch database engines?), I don't really see too many advantages.  It is, of course, the more "Eloquent" and "Laravel" way of doing things - which by itself will be enough of a sell to the framework purists out there.

If anything, I think using query builder would make onboarding a new developer that much harder.  SQL is a universal language that almost all developers know.  If you have a new member on your team who doesn't know Laravel well, chances are it'll take him a day to get up to speed with query builder.

I have come to accept to using relationships in my Eloquent models for simple one table joins, or two table joins using a reference table.  But anything requiring more than two joins, you should really be writing out your own SQL or using query builder.  And out of the two choices, I personally prefer writing raw SQL.

Comment: I think a lot of people are really missing a huge trick here, I have found Query builders substantially superior to other methods in both keeping code DRY, and enforcing SoC (by having different classes decorate a query builder with only 'information requests' that are only relevant for them) and finally by being able to have them express a DSL (by providing meaningful method names for the parts that I separate out for code reuse). Complex queries can be made far better understood that way. Many query builders do not allow adding columns in multiple gos though, rendering them useless to me.