# Laravel 5 eloquent query confusion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have some confusion on what's the difference with this codes. I have been accustomed in using eloquent like

```
$users = User::all(); 

//OR

$users = User::get();
```

But I have some training and our trainer uses DB

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get()
```

My question is which code is good to use and which is faster?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419196/4212912

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 2 require an eloquent model. The latter does not.

The eloquent model gives you easier options for customization. You can set soft deletes on the model and never worry about checking the flag in your query.

So it just depends how much abstraction you'd like.

You should certainly choose one or the other.

Comment: so its okay to stick with $users = User::all(); than $users = DB::table('users')->get() since its short code?

Comment: Yup. *if you make a matchng  eloquent model.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me the advantages of using eloquent model or some reference I can read in your answer, before accepting your answer. Thank you..

Comment: It's in the docs "Note: Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries." http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#introduction

Comment: Also check out the answer Dean Tran linked to.